# React native keyChain is not persist data

Tags: react-native, redux, keychain, persist

I am using react-native-keyChain for storing passwords and usernames in keychain. My website is in development mode. I am running an app in a simulator and I am also building an app on mobile using Xcode.

Here is my code how I am storing data into keyChain.

This is redux action function

```
export function fetchLoginDetails(loginData) {
    console.log(loginData)
    return async function fetchLoginDetailsThunk(dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(setLoading(true))
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.post(`url/login`, loginData);
            if (data.statuscode === 200) {
                await Keychain.setGenericPassword(loginData.email, loginData.password, {
                    service: 'org.AppNameKeyStore',
                    keychainAccessGroup: 'AppNameKeyStore.com.AppName'
                })
                await dispatch(setEmail(loginData.email));
                await dispatch(setUserId(data.data.id));
                Toast.show({
                    text1: `Otp has been sent to registered email`,
                    type: 'success',
                    position: 'bottom'
                })
            }
            dispatch(setLoading(false))
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(setError(error.response.data.message))
            Toast.show({
                text1: `${error.response.data.message}`,
                duration: 3000,
                type: 'error',
                position: 'bottom'
            })
            dispatch(setLoading(false))
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I am retrieving code

```
 useEffect(() => {
        getkeyChainValue();
    }, []);


    const getkeyChainValue = async () => {

        const options = {
             service: 'org.AppNameKeyStore'
        };

        const password = await Keychain.getGenericPassword(options);

        console.log(password,'password')
    
    }

//if the application does not reload it gives back a response. 

{"password": "password", "service": "org.AppNameKeyStore", "storage": "keychain", "username": "username@email.com"}
```

Once I reload the application from the terminal all data is erased.

is always returns false.

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Same issue on my side as well.

Comment: Does this happen on Android only?

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I am on android. Switching to setInternetCredentials works as expected.

Comment: Hi @ArtanM. 
I tried setInternetCredentials but not working on my end. 
Could you please share the snippet of yours?
Thanks